# ADB is not recognizing my device

Tags: android, mobile, adb, driver, device

This is not like other questions:

I already have installed:

- ADT
- Samsung Kies 3 (because I have a Samsung Galaxy S5)
- Google USB Driver

I already have configured:

- Developer options in my device enabled
- USB Debugging enabled

My computer and Kies recognizes my device, but adb doesn't!

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64-bits

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Have to successfully installed `Android ADB Interface Driver` for your phone?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Check [this](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and [this](http://www.mediafire.com/download/41lx6p71xxit1ax/ADB+Drivers_Updated.zip) out! :)

Comment: Your solution worked for me, but I had to unplug and replug my phone a few times in between attempts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem was that windows does not recognize the device driver, therefore is needed install it manually. The way I solved this:

**1. Open Device Manager and locate your device under “Other devices”.**
[image]

**2. Right click on your device and then click on “Update driver software”.**

**3. Now click on “Browse my computer for driver software” option.**
[image]

**4. In next screen, click on the option “Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer”.**

**5. Now select “Show All Devices” option and click the next button.**

[image]

**6. Now click on “Have Disk…” button. A window will pop up, click the browse button and browse to following location: D:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\usb_driver and select android_winusb.inf file.**

**Note:** If you installed / extracted the Android SDK to a different location, browse to that location instead of D:\

**7. In next screen, select “Android Composite ADB Interface” and click the “Next” button.**

[image]

**8. Confirm installation by clicking “Yes” and “Install” if you see any warning messages appear in Windows.**

**9. Android ADB drivers on Windows will now be installed for your device. You will see a confirmation message.**

**SOURCE:**

I took this solution from the following link. I started from step 7:

http://donandroid.com/how-to-install-adb-interface-drivers-windows-7-xp-vista-623

Comment: Helped me today! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know that, @Chad! My pleasure!

Comment: Worked like miracle.. Struggled for so long.

Comment: @TechieBrij glad I could help! Good coding!

Comment: Nice, but now i have to do this every time i connect my device. How do i "save" this relationship between driver and device?

Answer (score 14):

For those who already have developer options and USB debugging enabled, make sure you have the latest Samsung driver, which can be downloaded here:

http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117

Comment: After updating to Android 5 I got the same error .. In Developer Options the USB debugging had got disabled ... I had to reenable that

Comment: This should come without saying, but it took me 10 min to figure out that I needed to run it as admin. I kept clicking on it, and nothing happened...

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue and I followed the below link post which the issue solved.

http://donandroid.com/how-to-install-adb-interface-drivers-windows-7-xp-vista-623