# Samsung Duos S2 is not connecting with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, drivers

My mobile Samsung Galaxy Duos S2 was successfully connecting with Eclipse but suddenly Eclipse cannot detect my device. I have USB drivers and everything installed and my mobile is recognized by my computer, but Eclipse is not connecting to it. All other devices connect successfully via Eclipse. Is there a way of checking that a particular device has drivers for Eclipse, or any other way to connect the device with Eclipse?

Comment: Have to successfully installed `Android ADB Interface Driver` for your phone?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-not-recognizing-samsung-galaxy-s5/24265006#24265006](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-not-recognizing-samsung-galaxy-s5/24265006#24265006)

Comment: Yes these were installed but I uninstalled them because I thought these were the drivers that were blocking the detection of my samsung device. but my device is still not connecting with eclipse and also I tried kies but my mobile is connected to kies but not to eclipse. It is that eclipse is not capturing my device or some thing.

Comment: @FA If you uninstall then your phone won't connect to Eclipse becoz it's required....so try again ....

Comment: I have now completely installed all drivers but eclipse is showing my device offline and target is showing unknown.

Comment: That means you'll `Enable USB Debugging` into your Phone....

Comment: I think i have found my problem by uninstalling pdanet software that was causing my device not to connect to the computer and eclipse. the software was interfering in connecting the device to the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're missing Samsung's universal USB drivers for mobile devices.

You can download a version from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11633550#post11633550).

Or, download the latest Samsung USB drivers from [Bittorrent](https://thepiratebay.se/torrent/11032493/Samsung_USB_Drivers_for_Mobile_Devices_v1.5.45_Installer).

Then install Samsung USB drivers onto your computer.

**Note**: In Windows, simply relying on the Windows USB drivers will not successfully connect your device via ADB to Eclipse for Android development.