# ADB not recognize the android device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, driver

Here I am using [HTC Desire 626 G+](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_desire_626g+-7183.php) to debug android application. Last week I formatted my pc and install windows 10 for it. Then I install android studio and android SDK and all necessary components and [Universal Windows ADB Driver](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver)   . Then I connect my android device but it did not recognized by ADB. I first thought was something wrong with my device and cable. Then I change both and try to debug but result was same.
I want to say a word about Universal Windows ADB Driver. Before it works fine for me but now not. I also contact the HTC support center and I asked do I want to install driver to debug. But they specify that there is no drivers for my device.

I also follow questions regarding on this topic in **stackoverflow**. 
But I did not able to debug.

Also in my device manager show my android device as a unrecognized device.
Then I try to install  google usb drivers in Android SDK but it fail to install to my device.

Then I try to install Universal Windows ADB Driver to device in device manager. But It also fail.

What should I do now. I am really helpless ??

Comment: This will help to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-device

Comment: @Sunny It worked bro...
But unfortunately I cannot up vote you bro... Sorry

Comment: Good to hear that. np :)

Answer (score 0):

try to set the USB connection mode of your device from a Media Device (MTP) connection to a Camera Device (PTP) connection

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/configuring-your-windows-usb-android-debug-connection-for-the-intel-xdk

http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/