# Android Studio not detecting Samsung S3 physical device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

using Android Studio 2.3.1 on windows 7, i created my own app and is running normally on emulator but it doesn't detect my Samsung S3 physical device. I have tried all the recommended steps: Enabled USB debugging and downloaded and installed google device driver. When i tried to manually set debugging property to true in the AndroidMainfest.xml file i got an error when running the app. I'm not sure if i edited the correct Manifest file as i got multiple search results in different locations.

Comment: try the adb commands `adb devices` in your command prompt by providing it path to your sdk location and tell what it shows

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm new to Android Studio and Android development, first of all by command prompt do you mean the terminal inside android studio? and what kind of command would that look like?

Comment: open your cmd inside platform-tools folder located inside your sdk. then in cmd type the above command and revert back with the details. You can run in terminal too but it should also point to sdk path as said above

Comment: @VivekMishra I did what asked me for. It listed no devices at first, but when i ran the emulator, i typed the command again and it showed "emulator-5554    device".

Comment: now try running these 2 commands `adb kill-server` and after this `adb satart-server`. After this again run adb devices again.

Comment: i assume that was a typo and you meant 'adb start-server'. Same results, nothing shows, when i run the emulator and type adb devices, the emulator device shows up only

Comment: can you normally connect your device to your system?

Comment: Yes, It shows up in my explorer and i can access it and go through the folders and perform copy, paste, etc ..., the only issue seems to be inside Android.

Comment: last thing did you allowed usb debugging dialog which is showed when you connect your device

Comment: Yes, i did. I will try to connect another android device (HTC) to see if that would make a difference, although i'm positive it wouldn't. Maybe i need to manually set debugging to true in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Answer found here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here ...
[ADB is not recognizing my device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264562/adb-is-not-recognizing-my-device)

It looks even thought my device was showing under Control Panel/Device Manager/portable devices, It was detected as anonymous device under Control Panel/Device Manager/Other devices. Had to reinstall the driver as showed in the above answer